# How to get matrix format in php

Tags: php, arrays, matrix

```
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){    
  for($j=1;$j<21;$j++){
     echo $values[$i][$j]["score$j"];
  }
}
```

The above code gives the result as

```
65432123456543212349
  00000000000000000000
  10543212345654321234
```

Now I want this result to be in matrix(5*4) format. Eg.

```
 1=> 6 5 4 3 
     2 1 2 3
     4 5 6 5
     4 3 2 1
     2 3 4 9 

 2=> 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 0
```

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: You'd need to break the line whenever its needed

Comment: `echo implode("\n", array_chunk(implode(" ", array_chunk($values[$i][$j]["score$j"], 1)), 8));`

Comment: @saran Consider accepting my answer so this question doesn't get any more unneeded attention.

Answer (score 0):

Use [modulus](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to determine if your second loop reaches the 4th element and add a new line plus spacing if so.

Also add the key and the `=>` part before entering the second foreach.

Something like [this](http://ideone.com/ILPaG4):

```
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){    
echo "\n" . $i . " => ";    
  for($j=1;$j<21;$j++){
     echo $values[$i][$j]["score$j"]. " ";
     if($j % 4 === 0) {
       echo "\n    ";           
     }
  }
}
```

If you would provide the content of `$values` in PHP form, we could give a better solution.